# Unity не открывается

Tags: unity3d, 3d

Unity 2018.1.5f1 не открывается. Висит загрузка и ничего не происходит минут 10.

[image: unity]

Что делать?

Comment: Наверное переустановить юньку, либо почистить кеш

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Попробую.

Comment: У вас, случайно, проблем с интернетом нету? Unity к нему порой сильно цепляется - может и вот так зависнуть.

Comment: Да нет, нэт быстрый, проблем нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте поставить Unity hub, если что загрузите новую версию (тут удобно это реализовано).
Ну а проблема похожая была и у меня, решил переустановкой на новый диск, ибо старый накрывался, проверьте может и у вас тоже.
Так же обратите внимание, что если вы не активировали какую либо лицензию, то **Unity не откроется**. Потому обязательно зайдите в хаб и проконфигурируйте лицензию.

-(ссылка) https://unity3d.com/ru/get-unity/download

Comment: Ок, я попробую.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно причины в сети, Unity пытается подключиться к серверу, но по каким-то причинам не получается. Попробуйте отключится от сети(подключится к другой)

У меня такое всегда, когда я в корпоративной сети которая блокирует порты, которые использует в том числе Unity.

Answer (score 1):

У меня когда-то была такая проблема, попробуйте открыть Unity от имени администратора.

Вероятно, это баг. Так что установка другой версии, тоже, должна помочь.

Answer (score 1):

У меня недавно была такая же проблема, когда я работал оффлайн, вы работаете оффлайн?

Если да то перезапустите unity или подключитесь сети. Я не знаю с чем оно связано, но это помогало. (или просто поставь другую версию юнити).

Comment: Оффлайн редко работаю, но Unity запускается только при оффлайне. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Если вы онлайн, и загрузочный экран висит, то значит вы сидите через какой то всратый vpn или у вас ооочень слабый интернет

Comment: У меня ни того, ни другого. Дело в самой юньке.